faceted color=none in surface plot with fill option
I have the following code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}

        \addplot3 [
        domain y=0:2,
        domain=-2:2,
        surf,
        % faceted color=none,
        faceted color=pink,
        fill=pink,
        opacity=0.2,
        samples y=20,
        samples=20,
        ] {2};

        \addplot3 [
        domain y=0:2,
        domain=-2:2,
        surf,
        faceted color=none,
        samples y=20,
        samples=20,
        ] {1};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

What I want is to remove the edge colors in the first plot.
According to the documentation that should work by setting faceted color=none but it doesn't.
It does in the second plot where I did not use fill and opacity.
Did I miss something in the documentation? How can I remove the edge colors in the first plot?
Thank you for any help!

Normally, you should use shader=flat to remove the mesh lines. But it seems this doesn't work well with opacity, like with faceted color=none.
As a workaround, you can set the opacity for the drawing and the filling separately
fill opacity=0.2,
draw opacity=0,

Example:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}

    \addplot3 [
      domain y=0:2,
      domain=-2:2,
      surf,
      fill=pink,
      fill opacity=0.2,
      draw opacity=0,
      samples y=20,
      samples=20,
    ] {2};

    \addplot3 [
      domain y=0:2,
      domain=-2:2,
      surf,
      faceted color=none,
      samples y=20,
      samples=20,
    ] {1};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



I tried to use a shader and/or draw opacity option. But it did not work. Apparently the order of the options also has an effect.
